# AWS S3 PutObjectAsync ETag not matching MD5

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, md5

I'm trying to upload a file to S3 (PutObjectAsync) and then check that it's got there OK.

I'm finding my generated MD5 hash is not matching the returned ETag, whats the correct way to verify the file?

```
                using (var fileDataStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
                    {
                        file.CopyTo(fileDataStream);

                        var hash = md5.ComputeHash(fileDataStream.ToArray());
                        var hashAsString = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);

                        var request = new PutObjectRequest
                        {
                            CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead,
                            InputStream = fileDataStream,
                            BucketName = _optionsAws.Value.MediaBucketName,
                            Key = s3FileName
                        };

                        var result = await _s3Client.PutObjectAsync(request);

                        if (result.ETag != hashAsString)
                        {
                            ret.isSuccess = false;
                            ret.errorMessage = "Non matching hash";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ret.isSuccess = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem.  Solved it this way and the MD5 hash matched up to the ETag from the S3 upload just fine, although I did have to trim off the '"' (double quote) character from the ETag response.  I do not believe this will work if you upload the file in multi-parts.

```
     public static string CalculateMD5Hash(byte[] bytes)
        {
            MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
            byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(bytes);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("x2"));
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
```